# Box2D Creating World

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm using Box2D on Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013, but something not right when I try to create a b2World. It gives me this kinds of errors:

---

mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1900' doesn't match value '1800' in Box.obj

unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)

unresolved external symbol ___std_terminate

unresolved external symbol ___std_terminate

unresolved external symbol ___std_terminate

unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func

unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf

---

And the lines of code that gives the errors are this ones:

```
b2Vec2 gravity(0, -9.8);
bool doSleep = true;
b2World bbworld(gravity);
```

If I comment this line:

```
b2World bbworld(gravity);
```

nothing happens

Note: Box is a class on my program!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is `Box.obj` created from one of your source files (e.g. `Box.cpp`)? Did you build it with a previous version of MSVC++? Have you tried rebuilding the project from scratch? Tried removing the `Debug` and/or `Release` folders before rebuilding?

Comment: Box.obj is a class and has noting related with Box2D. I don't use Box2D on Box.cpp. I tried to clean and rebuild the program and nothing happened

Comment: Nothing happened, as in *nothing* happened, or as in "still the same results"?

Answer (score 3):

Include such compiler options to solve the "unresolved external symbol ___std_terminate" problem:

**/Zc:threadSafeInit-,sizedDealloc-,implicitNoexcept-**

Also check if you're not removing all default C runtime libraries, the linker option: **/NODEFAULTLIB**

Comment: This worked for me when I made sure the linker option was set to no.  Thanks for the help.